# Why Cross Platform Development Template not showing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I recently installed the Visual Studio Community 2015 in Windows 10  for the cross plat form development. unfortunately I cannot see any cross platform development under the new project. Is there any additional setup for it or not. How can I get it....  Pls help

Regards,
SNair

Answer (score 2):

May be you didn't install it

1 - Run Setup.exe file again.

2- Select Modify

3 - now you see options that you can select. Select Cross Platform Mobile Development.

4- click UPDATE

Comment: According to what i saw modifying needs an internet connection

Comment: I've been able to create a xamarin cross platform app before and now I don't have the option to create it anymore. Any ideas?